# InDesign CS5 Script: How can I place another InDesign document into a new InDesign document?

Tags: document, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am creating a new InDesign document with  `var newDoc = app.documents.add()` .

I am trying to place another pre-existing InDesign document that has paragraph styles into the new document. The reason why I'm not simply using  `styledDocument.execute()`  is that it opens this pre-existing document, whereas I want the document itself to be "`Untitled`".

I am attempting to do this with  `newDoc.place(styledDocument)` , which is not working. The document is untitled as intended, but has the styled document as a link only, and is ***not*** populating the  `Paragrah Styles`  window with the styles from the styled document...

---

It *is* possible from  `File --> Place...`  in the InDesign menu to open another InDesign document into this one *manually*, in which the styles from this document ***do*** appear in the  `Paragrah Styles`  window... But I want to programmatically do this. So, I am assuming that  `File --> Place...`  from the InDesign menu is different than  `newDoc.place(oldDoc)`.

---

Here is my code (which is *not* working):

```
var newDoc = app.documents.add();
newDoc.place(styledDocument);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wawawaaa, what is your final intention ? Load styles from doc A into Doc B ? If that so, why not use the document's importStyles method ? 
If you do want to import document as an image, you can use the place method and specify the document as any other image file.

Comment: Haha ok, I was confusing myself with this question. Yes, importing styles from doc A into doc B is exactly what I want to do. And looking into the `importStyles` method, I am making this statement: `myDocument.importStyles(ImportFormat.paragraphStylesFormat, File(styledDocument), GlobalClashResolutionStrategy.loadAllWithOverwrite);`. Thanks for the help Loic.

Comment: I have found information at jongware on this method here:  http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Document.html. But for more specific information, http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/indesign/pdfs/InDesignCS5_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf has a great code sample implementing this.